# Como definir um método que receba uma expressão lâmbda?

Tags: c++, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho uma classe semelhante a essa e queria que o código que ela executasse fosse passado como uma expressão lâmbda.

```
class T {
public:
    double execute();
};
```

Por exemplo:

```
T t;
int a = 0, b = 1;
t.execute([a,b]()->double{return (3*a + 5*b);});
```

Como ficaria a definição do método execute()? Continuaria como está? E a passagem da expressão lâmbda seria assim mesmo?
Tentei inferir como seria o código olhando esse site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O OP encontrou uma solução usando ponteiros de função. Ele escolheu passar o ponteiro pelo construtor e armazená-lo na classe. Outra possibilidade é passar o ponteiro de função diretamente para a função `execute`:

```
class T {
public:
    double execute(double (*expression)()) {
        return expression();
    }
};

int main() {
    T t;
    double result = t.execute([]() -> double {return 1 + 1;});
    return 0;
}
```

Ponteiros de função possuem uma sintaxe estranha, não permitem captura de variáveis do contexto (i.e, *closures*) e *inlining*.

#### [Veja funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/a3zQ8j).

---

Caso você precise de *closures* ou *inline* é possível utilizar um *template* para generalizar a expressão. Para boa parte dos casos essa é melhor maneira de passar uma função qualquer como parâmetro:

```
class T {
public:
    template<typename Func>
    double execute(Func expression) {
        return expression();
    }
};

int main() {
    T t;
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    double result = t.execute([&a,&b]() -> double {return 3 * a + 5 * b;}); 
    return 0;
}
```

As principais limitações da versão com *template* são:

1. Não é possível "armazenar" esse tipo fora da classe
2. A implementação precisa estar junto ao *header*

#### [Veja funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/yJWDQu).

---

Caso as limitações acima sejam um problema, é possível recorrer à [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), um *wrapper* para ponteiros de função, *functors*, *lambdas*, etc.

```
class T {
public:
    double execute(std::function<double()> expression) {
        // sem templates, expression pode ser "armazenada" em qualquer lugar
        return expression();
    }
};

int main() {
    T t;
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    // [&] captura qualquer variavel por referencia
    std::function<double()> func = [&]() -> double {return 3 * a + 5 * b;};
    double result = t.execute(func);   
    return 0;
}
```

Enquanto o uso de `std::function` é mais *genérico* quando comparado à ponteiros de função, o *wrapper* resulta em *overhead* durante a chamada. Também não é possível utilizar `std::function` com versões anteriores ao C++11 ou com `inline`.

#### [Veja funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/SOdz0h).

---

### Referências:

1. [SOen: Should I use std::function or a function pointer in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25848690/664577)
2. [Lambda Functions in C++11 - the Definitive Guide](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2LywvCM9/)

Comment: Muito boa essa solução com o rapper. A vantagem de poder ser armazenado sobressai sobre a desvantagem do overhead. Além disso a sintaxe fica bem mais clara.

Comment: Sim, para ser justo você poderia "armazenar" uma referência usando o template dentro da própria classe (a maior falha na minha opinião dessa abordagem, na minha opinião, é que templates de função não funcionam direito com `auto`). Dito isso, do ponto de vista de *design* `std::function`  é realmente bem flexível.

Answer (score 3):

Achei a solução. Ela ficou assim:

```
class T {
private:
    double (*expression)();
public:
    T(double (*exp)()) : expression(exp) {}
    double execute() {
        return this->expression();
    }
};

int main() {
    T t([]()->double {return 1+1;});
    double val = t.execute(); // val = 2
    return 0;
}
```

Não era exatamente como eu queria mas resolveu o problema.